# MVC 3: HTML.DisplayFor and the Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have found other topics regarding this, but none of them made me understand what I'm trying to figure out.

I am studying MVC 3 and I have problems wrapping my head around the Lambda expressions that go with @HTML.DisplayFor() in the scaffolding template.

I am working with the MvcMusicStore sample application, the view created by the scaffolding looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>

...

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
        </td>
```

I understand that DisplayFor is a extension method to HTML and that it takes an expression as a parameter. I researched Lambda expressions and understand them in other contexts such as with enumerable strings. For example:

```
cities.Where(s => s.StartsWith("L"));
```

What boggles my mind is, that in the second example, the first part of the expression (s) is actually used in the second part (s.startswith..), so it makes sense and I get what the program is doing with it. But this is not the case in the MVC 3 view. modelItem is not beeing used anywhere. I tried renaming just "modelItem" to whatever like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(iAmWearingShortPantsToday => item.Genre.Name)
```

This code works just as well, displaying all the items and values correctly. This makes me doubt that in this case "modelItem" is actually used for anything. But then, why is it there?

I have also tried to translate this Lambda expression into a delegate (which I believe it is the short form for), like this:

```
@(Html.DisplayFor(delegate(IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album> modelItem) { return item.Genre.Name; }))
```

This however, does not work. The resulting error is:

*CS1946: An anonymous method expression cannot be converted to an expression tree*

Hence my question:

What is "modelItem" good for? What does HTML.DisplayFor() do with modelItem? Are there other cases maybe, where this first part of the expression becomes significant?

If it's possible to translate this expression into a proper delegate, that might also help me to understand what's exactly going on.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

I understand your confusion. Actually `modelItem` variable is never used in the lambda expression. What is used is the `item` variable which is captured in a closure from the outer context. The `item` variable is simply the local variable defined in the `foreach` loop.

By the way when you see an expression like `modelItem => item.Genre.Name` in ASP.NET MVC view, that's usually a sign for a bad coding practice. Avoid it. The internet is swarming with such bad examples. Really. I am sick of seeing this. Please help me eradicate this practice.

Here's an alternative method in which the variable is actually used:

```
@model IList<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>
...

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Genre.Name)
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
}
```

And even better. Why write loops at all? When we can directly use editor/display templates:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>
...
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

and then define a display template that will automatically be rendered by ASP.NET MVC for each element of the model collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Album.cshtml`)

```
@model Album
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Genre.Name)
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you used a `for` instead of a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Yes, the particular reason is that there are millions of questions on StackOverflow using `foreach` and input fields inside it, like `@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Name)` and asking why the POST action doesn't get any values back. Why the model is always null. Do you know why?

Comment: 1: You say modelItem => item.Genre.Name is bad practice. But this is exactly what comes out of the default MVC 3 scaffolding. How can this be bad practice? It's also in the book I am reading, Professional MVC 3 by Wrox.
2: So if the modelItem is not used, why is it there? Have you got a theory?

Comment: Bad practice. That's my theory :-) Don't use it. Use editor/display templates instead. Every single day I have to answer questions about people having problems with this. Here's one I answered today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11682510/29407. The OP used the exactly same code as you. And believe, every single day this process repeats that I am so sick of it. You don't believe it's bad practice? Then that's your own problem. Feel free to use it in this case but when later you encounter problems with model binding remember this question you have asked in the past :-)

Comment: In your example you are using display templates (DisplayFor) so it doesn't really matter. But then, without realizing, you start adapting this foreach concept to EditorTemplates and which is when your problems will start.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can answer your question, but the right part is used to tell `DisplayFor` which property is will create a display for. It is used to determine the type of the property (used to select how to display the value) and the value.

If used in a TextBoxFor, it is also used to retrieve the name of the property, so the textbox can get the proper name.

I think that the expression in a lot of the html-helper extension methods is actually a bit odd, but it's the easy way of letting the code get all these information, without you having to write it down as string parameters (that would fail if you changed anything, without giving a compile-time error).