# Create view for complex type in list initializes values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11682510/801005 in a common question.
This works fine for editing data but not really for creating data when you want to add a complex type to the list immediately.

If you make a create action in your controller, you should create an instance of the `AssignSoftwareLicenseViewModel` and create an instance of the `ICollection<SelectableDeviceViewModel> Devices`. After that you have to create an instance of the `SelectableDeviceViewModel` and add it to the collection. Then return the created `AssignSoftwareLicenseViewModel` to the view.

All the textboxes are created fine and the post works as well. But because you create an instance of the object, `LicenseId` has the value `0` on your screen. If you also have a `DateTime` property you would get `01-01-0001` as default value in your textbox on your screen.

How do I remove those values? My display attribute is useless now...

Sample datetime:

```
[Display(Name = "Geboortedatum")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
```

Sample Create

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    AssignSoftwareLicenseViewModel vm = new AssignSoftwareLicenseViewModel();
    vm.Devices = new Collection<SelectableDeviceViewModel>();
    vm.Devices.Add(new SelectableDeviceViewModel());

    return View(vm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your model properties as nullable types and you shouldn't have this problem.

```
public DateTime? BirthDay { get; set; }
public int? LicenseId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes but then my database with ef code First is corrupted. I could solve the problem with a viewmodel but I want to know if it could be solved on another way

Comment: You would indeed have to reinitialize your db if using code-first, is that a problem?

Comment: Well it isn't really an issue for me todo but it's just wrong to fix an ui problem by redesigning your backend. I guess it isn't possible without creating a viewmodel