# MVC5 - ViewModel with Complex types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, html-helper, checkboxfor

I can not find a solution for a problem like this.  If this is a duplicate post I am sorry.

I am modeling my solution on this

[MVC3 - Viewmodel with list of complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677831/mvc3-viewmodel-with-list-of-complex-types)

My ViewModel (ZooAnimalsViewModel) contains both a list of possible animals as well as an ICollection.

I am trying to populate the linking table between Zoo and Animal - the table is ZooAnimalDetail.  I pass ZooAnimalsViewModel as the model to the main view
and Animal as the model to the EditorTemplate file allAnimals.cshtml.

From what I have seen I am supposed to use the framework to generate the list by creating a file in the EditorTemplate directory with the same name as the list/collection I want to display.

I want to display the list allAnimals and use it to update what is contained in the ICollection ZooAnimalDetail - I can not figure out how to write a Html helper to bind them.

The simplified ViewModel ZooAnimalViewModel has the following properties:

```
public class ZooAnimalViewModel
    {
        public Zoo zoo { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ZooAnimalDetail> ZooAnimalDetail { get; set; }
        public List<Animal> allAnimals { get; set; }
    }
```

The simplified model for ZooAnimalDetail is as follows:

```
  public partial class ZooAnimalDetail
      {
          public int zooID { get; set; }
          public int animalID { get; set; }
          public bool animalDefault { get; set; }
          public virtual Animal Animal { get; set; }
          public virtual Zoo Zoo { get; set; }
      }
```

The simplified model for Animal is as follows:

```
public partial class Animal
{
   public Animal()
   {
       ZooAnimalDetails = new HashSet<ZooAnimalDetail>();
   }
   public int animalID { get; set; }
   public string animalName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ZooAnimalDetail> ZooAnimalDetails { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I create a new ZooAnimalViewModel object and initialize zoo to the current zoo and allAnimals to contain a list of all animals who potentially could live at that zoo.

In my view I am trying to display all the items in the allAnimals list with 2 checkboxes.
If checkbox 1 is selected add this animal to the zoo.
If checkbox 2 is selected animalDefault is set to true.

The simplified view looks like this

```
@model ZooAnimalViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.zoo.zooID)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Animal Name</th>
            <th>Add</th>
            <th>Set as default</th>
        </tr>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.allAnimals)
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

In ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/allAnimals.cshtml I have tried to set up the view

```
@model DatabaseName.Models.Animal
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.animalID)
<tr>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ZooAnimalDetail.??)</td>  @*PROBLEM 1*@
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ZooAnimalDetail.Add(animalDefault))</td> @*PROBLEM 2*@
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.animalName)</td>
</tr>
```

PROBLEM 1 - I want to display a checkbox for each animal in my list - if it is checked I want this animal to be added to the zoo  - so ZooAnimalDetail for this zooID and animalID will exist.

PROBLEM 2 - If the animal is chosen to be added to the zoo and the second checkbox is checked I want to set animalDefault in ZooAnimalDetail to true.

Am I approaching this the right way?

**Edit**

Moving Forward

I added the boolean field IsChecked to the ZooAnimalDetail class

I created  ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ZooAnimalDetail.cshtml as follows

```
  @model DatabaseName.Models.ZooAnimalDetail
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.animalID)
  <tr>
      <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)</td>
      <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.animalDefault)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Animal.animalName)</td>
  </tr>
```

Instead of using

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.allAnimals) in the view

I use

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ZooAnimalDetail)

After I pass the ZooAnimalViewModel (zavm) back to the Post Controller I save it to the database so a zooID will be generated.

I use a foreach loop to select only those Animals that have the IsChecked set to true to update the ZooAnimalDetail entity.

```
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           db.Zoos.Add(zavm.zoo);
           db.SaveChanges();

           //grab the new zooID
           int lastzooID = db.Zoos.Max(item => item.zooID);

           foreach (ZooAnimalDetail z in zavm.ZooAnimalDetail)
           {
               if (z.IsChecked == true)
               {
                    z.zooID = lastzooID;
                    db.ZooAnimalDetails.Add(z);
               }
           }                
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
```

I no longer need the allAnimals list in my ZooAnimalViewModel.

Seems to work alright.

Comment: Quick note - I used the NotMapped attribute when I added the boolean IsChecked field like this     
         
       `[NotMapped]
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }`